# Remove border on far left and far right

Tags: html, css-tables

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/mVX93/48/

Is it possible to remove the border from the far left side and far right hand side of the table?

I want to align it to either side of the page, and you can see it doesn't align with the test text. My idea would be to use nth item to apply `border-left: 0px;` to the first item and `border-right: 0px` to the last item however this doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone show me if this is possible and how it should be implemented please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have `border-spacing:10px;` there will be space remaining on the right and left side to separate the `td`. However, you could put a `div` around the table and change it's `margin-left` and `margin-right`.

Try this:

```
body {
    background-color: gray;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.grid {
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
}
```

You cell 4's text is overflowing but it is because you have a lot of `.` or dots without a space so when you enter text it should be fine.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8sw9v/1)**

Answer (score 0):

If you change the border-spacing to border-spacing-left:0px it aligns with Test but reduces the space between the cells. If you also add another Test and float it right it aligns with the right side of the table.